# PHP on Nginx crashes after some minutes

Tags: linux, nginx, php, fastcgi

I'm having a embedded device with a running OpenWrt Linux. I have installed and configured the pakages `php5-fastcgi` and `nginx` like described on OpenWrt Wiki: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/http.nginx Furthermore I have installed the packages `php5-mod-session` and `php5-mod-sockets`.

Everything seems to work correctly basic files like images, static HTML pages etc. as well as PHP scripts.

My web page has a JS script (AJAX) which polls a PHP script every second. After about 5 to 10 minutes nginx responses with a `502 Bad Gateway` error on all PHP pages. If I check the running process on my linux machine I can see that the process `php5-fastcgi` isn't running anymore. The PHP log is empty and the log of Nginx shows the connection error to the FastCGI server of PHP only.

I know there are lot of topics about this on the internet but I didn't find a solution yet.

Maybe anyone could help! Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: I would start by checking the log levels of PHP-FPM, set it to debug. It should at a minimum say "starting up now", but once it's working should give you some good clues about what's up. Once a second seems very fast for PHP on an embedded device, PHP is quite heavy. It may run out of RAM and kill the process. Check memory usage with top. Also configure the number of PHP workers to 1 or 2, to see what happens.

Comment: PHP-FPM is a separate package (`php5-fpm`) which replaces `php5-fastcgi`. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry I can't answer that for sure, but I suspect they're different. I know I use php-fpm with Nginx on Amazon Linux and it works well.

Comment: OK. Thanks so far. I will try to install `php5-fpm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what causes my issue with PHP and Nginx. But after replacing `php-fastcgi` through `php-fpm` everything seems to work now.